# Vue.js: The required fields get highlighted even before submitting in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, vue.js

In macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 and Firefox Version 56.0.2 (64-bit), the required fields get highlighted even before submitting, any help to fix this issue will be great help.

This works fine as the data `radioInputVal` is `string`:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    radioInputVal: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label for="input1">1:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input1" required value="1" v-modal="radioInputVal" />
    <br />
    <label for="input2">2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input2" value="2" v-modal="radioInputVal" />
    <br />
    <label for="input3">3:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input3" value="3" v-modal="radioInputVal" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
  </form>
  
</div>
```

This doesn't work fine as it's data `radioInputObj` is an object.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    radioInputObj: {
      val: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label for="input1">1:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input1" required value="1" v-model="radioInputObj.someVal" />
    <br />
    <label for="input2">2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input2" value="2" v-model="radioInputObj.someVal" />
    <br />
    <label for="input3">3:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input3" value="3" v-model="radioInputObj.someVal" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
  </form>  
</div>
```

Below code is not linked to VUE.js and the required fields doesn't get highlighted until submitted.

```html
<form>
  <label for="input1">1:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="input1" required value="1" />
  <br />
  <label for="input2">2:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="input2" value="2" />
  <br />
  <label for="input3">3:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="input3" value="3" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see this. It works fine on FF

Comment: @samayo, sorry, forgot to mentioned the os details, I am useing macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 and Firefox Version 56.0.2 (64-bit)